# How to deploy a flask app which uses selenium using third party service like vercel?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, hosting, vercel, production

I have a flask application in python that uses selenium package (version 4.15.2) to scrape and download a excel workbook from a google sheet link. I have been successfully able to download and retrieve this file on my local host but when I deploy this app using hosting service like vercel the selenium driver crashes because the production environment in different from that of the local host. I have no idea how I can control the production environment on vercel. It is not necessary that I only use vercel to deploy and host my application. Any free third-party service that supports selenium would work for me.

I tried to include the chrome driver exe file with the rest of the contents of my upload on vercel. Also tried to run with different versions of selenium but the driver just won't run on production environment.